# CASE expression for data greater than zero for last three months

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I am trying to create a field to show active or inactive based on the below criteria:

Has 'A' in Active or Terminated Field
Revenue is greater than zero over past 4 months (including current month)

```
SELECT [NAME CODE]
  ,[NAME]
  ,[ACTIVE OR TERMINATED]
  ,REV.[REVENUE AMOUNT]
  ,REV.[MONTH]
  ,REV.[YEAR]
,CASE
  WHEN [ACTIVE OR TERMINATED] = 'A' 
  AND YEAR(GETDATE())= REV.[YEAR]
  AND [REVENUE AMOUNT] > 0
  AND REV.[MONTH] = FORMAT(DATEADD(month,-2 ,getdate()),'MM')
  AND REV.[MONTH] = FORMAT(DATEADD(month,-3 ,getdate()),'MM')
  THEN 'ACTIVE'
  ELSE 'INACTIVE'
END as [ACTIVE FLAG]
  FROM [ACTIVE_TABLE].[DBO]
  LEFT JOIN [REVENUE TABLE].[DBO] REV on [NAME CODE] = REV.[NAME CODE]
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: can you also add in the question the behaviour you are getting from this query?

Answer (score 0):

If you have one row for each month, you can use window functions.  You question is a bit hard to follow -- and not consistent with the query (in one case you mention revenue but it doesn't appear in the query).  The idea is something like this:

```
SELECT . . . ,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(REV.REVENUE) OVER (PARTITION BY REV.[NAME CODE]
                                         ORDER BY REV.MONTH
                                         ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                                        ) > 0
             THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'TTERMINATED'
        END) as ACTIVEFLAG
FROM [ACTIVE_TABLE].[DBO] LEFT JOIN
     [REVENUE TABLE].[DBO] REV 
     ON [NAME CODE] = REV.[NAME CODE];
```